# Using Jest to test a React component's method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a container component responsible for providing save functionality for a child form component method. I'm trying to use Jest & Enzyme (I think I need enzyme?) to test whether the child component fires the function passed from the parent component. The two methods look like so:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  handleSave = (someData) => (
    /* do some ajax with someData */
  )
  render() {
    return(
      <ChildComponent {...this.props} handleSave={this.handleSave} />
    )
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSave}>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  }
}
```

And the test:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ParentContainer from '../src/ParentContainer'

describe('<ParentContainer />', () => {

  it('Should fire handle save when PatientScheduler form saves', () => {
    const component = mount( <ParentContainer />)
    component.handleSave = jest.fn()
    component.find('[type="submit"]').simulate('click')
    expect(component.handleSave).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

})
```

The failure message I'm getting is `Expected mock function to have been called.`

I feel like I'm 90% of the way there. What's wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that simulate not really fire a click event but runs `wrapper.prop('click')()`. Form the docs:

> Common Gotchas
>
> Currently, event simulation for the shallow renderer does not
>   propagate as one would normally expect in a real environment. As a
>   result, one must call `.simulate()` on the actual node that has the
>   event handler set.
>
> Even though the name would imply this simulates an
>   actual event, `.simulate()` will in fact target the component's prop
>   based on the event you give it. For example, `.simulate('click')` will
>   actually get the `onClick` prop and call it.

So you can either run `component.find('form').simulate('submit')` or `component.find('form').prop('onSubmit')()`

Comment: OK, this solves the submission problem (thank you), but I'm still not sure how to spy on my handleSave method properly.

Comment: There are some flaws in you test mainly this line ` component.handleSave = jest.fn()`. You should not test on your internal behaviour but on the external stuff. In your case I assume you will use have some imported module that does the actual request. You have to mock and spy on this.